# Frobenius method, tricky indicial equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The given equation is
$$xy''-(2x-1)y'+(x-1)y=0$$
Now, I haven't learned anything about the Frobenius method beyond what I've read from the Wikipedia article on it, so I expect I might have done something incorrectly.

I substituted $y=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^{k+r}$ and I end up with the following:
$$r(r-1)a_0x^{r-2}+r(r+1)a_1x^{r-1}-2ra_0x^{r-1}+ra_0x^{r-2}+(r+1)a_1x^{r-1}-a_0x^{r-1}+\sum_{k=2}^\infty\bigg[(k+r)(k+r-1)a_k-2(k+r-1)a_{k-1}+(k+r)a_k+a_{k-2}-a_{k-1}\bigg]x^{k+r-2}$$
What's bothering me is the indicial equation... My attempt at solving gives me $r=0$ for the $x^{r-2}$ term, but I am unsure about the second term. I was under the impression the roots for it would be
$$r=\frac{(a_0-a_1)\pm\sqrt{a_0^2-3a_1a_0}}{a_1}$$
but I haven't come across any other examples that have roots written in terms of $a_i$.

Comment: Did you try to do this with : r=0 from the start? Because that's a two dimensional space of solutions so you won't get anything about $a_0$ or $a_1$, but it looks like you're gonna get an interesting relation between three consecutive terms of the expansion

Comment: I get: $ (k+2)^2*a_{k+2}-(2k+3)a_{k+1} +a_k =0 $ for $k \geq 0$

Comment: I don't know much about the method, but if you're interested in the solution, you may want to note since all 3 coefficients sum to $0$, it should be trivial to show that $e^x$ is a solution.

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1006832/solve-the-de-xy-2x-1yx-1y-0-using-frobenius-series. Is this equality true keynote=user170231

Answer (score 3):

$\textbf{If you are open to other methods}$

due to your following statement 
$\textit{"I haven't learned anything about the Frobenius method"}$

so if you need to just solve it you could use this trick(of sorts)

$$
xy'' - (2x-1)y' + (x-1)y = xy'' - xy' - (x-1)y' +(x-1)y = 0
$$

or

$$
x\left(y''-y'\right) - (x-1)\left(y'-y\right) = 0
$$
then let $v = y' - y$

then

$$
x\dfrac{dv}{dx} - (x-1)v = 0
$$

solve for v then you have

$$
y' - y = v(x)
$$